# certain characters behaving unusually within htmlentities function

Tags: php, html, html-entities

So first I noticed when an ampersand (&) is in the htmlentities function it will count the ampersand as 5 characters. So this code:

```
$a = htmlentities("&12345");
$b = substr($a,0,6);
  echo $b;
```

would echo `'&1'` as, I believe it is counting & as 5 characters.
more interestingly is with the GBP symbol (£) which is ignored all together so this:

```
$a = htmlentities("£");
  echo $a;
```

echos nothing. I get the same results on Chrome and FF. I don't know if this is a bug or I should use a different syntax. Does anyone know why this might be happening? Thanks

### UPDATE

I have solved the £ issue with this: `$a = htmlentities("£", ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-15');`
but the ampersand issue remains.

Comment: `echo htmlentities("£");` gives `&pound` at my end. Check raw source with "View source" in Chrome.

Comment: try mb_substr instead of substr. You are most likely seeing browser output and not html source output

Comment: tried it, but no change, thanks

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ here You can play around

Comment: Just use UTF-8 encoding throughout your system, and all these issue will go away. No need for entities, except for the key HTML ones (`&`, `<` and `>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are viewing the output in the browser window where output from `htmlentities` (and equivalent functions) is rendered for display to an end user.

For example:

```
echo htmlentities("&");
```

Will output `&amp;` because it has converted the `&` character to it's html entity equivalent. See that it is five characters long. However, you don't see the full text `&amp;` because you're viewing from your browser which has pre-rendered it as the `&` symbol. In firfox if you right click the viewport and click on "View Page Source" you will see the full text `&amp;`...

Your code:

```
$a = htmlentities("&12345"); //Outputs: &amp;12345
$b = substr($a, 0, 6); //Selects first six charachters: &, a, m, p, ; and 1
echo $b; // Echo's: &amp;1 which is displayed by the browser as &1
```

To get around this you can change the order of your functions:

```
$a = substr("&12345", 0, 6);
echo htmlentities($a);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Do you know how I could solve this problem?

Comment: So that it outputs: `&12345`? Yeah, there's a simple solution, just use `substr` **before** `htmlentities`. I.e. `htmlentities(substr("&12345", 0, 6));` -- See update in answer